# I need a four column image web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, sitepages

Using SharePoint online, I have created a SharePoint page structure, to include a 4th side column and this leaves me with maximum page column split of 3 on the remainder.

I am trying to add 4 image links, to feed to separate sub sites. I do not think there is any configuration changes available in the site structure. So the alternative is to look at a 4 image web part that can feed on a single column structure.

Or is there layout scripting available?

Comment: Try using quick links web part with "Tiles" layout: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-quick-links-web-part-e1df7561-209d-4362-96d4-469f85ab2a82. Let me know if it works for you.